# Iterating Over Regexp Matches with Sed and Bash?

Tags: regex, parsing, bash, sed

How can I iterate over multi-line regexp matches using sed and bash?
I'm trying to generate some quick docs from comments in a file, like so:

```
/**
 * @name myFun
 * @return {int}
 */
```

I can extract every comment block using `sed -n -e '/\/\*\*$/,/\*\/$/p'`, but now I'd like to stuff each match into a bash array so I can parse the details later.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd probably be better off using [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

By the way, your `sed` command *might* be more readable using alternate delimiters:

```
sed -n -e '\|/\*\*$|,\|\*/$|p'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would be looking to a scripting tool - I'd reach for Perl, but Python can probably handle it too.  I'd probably slurp the entire source file, then use a multi-line regex to pick up the comments.

The reason for not trying it in sed plus bash is that sed would output N-line comments, which you'd then have to split - and that would be tricky.